# How to delete a drawn string in JFrame

Tags: java, string, swing, jframe

So basically I want to have a number system on a JFrame panel. The number is displayed on the frame using this method.

```
public static void text(int x, int y, String text)
{
if (instance == null)
  throw new RuntimeException("Must call window method first");
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
g.setColor(color);
Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
g.setFont(font);
FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
int actualX = x - metrics.stringWidth(text) / 2;
int actualY = y + metrics.getAscent() / 2;
g.drawString(text, actualX, actualY);

instance.repaint();
}
```

When the value of the number increases I want it to replace the number up there with the new number. I know there has to be a way to do this but could someone help me with finding it? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear the drawn are, then draw the string again.

```
public static void image(int x, int y, int width, int height, String file)
{
if (instance == null)
  throw new RuntimeException("Must call window method first");
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
////
g.setColor(bgColor);//background color
g.fillRect(0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeigth());//clearing the are by filling a rectangle
////
g.setColor(color);
Font font = new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
g.setFont(font);
FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
int actualX = x - metrics.stringWidth(text) / 2;
int actualY = y + metrics.getAscent() / 2;
g.drawString(text, actualX, actualY);

instance.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I screwed up on the post a little. I put the first line for another class which adds an image. Could you help me on the text instead of the image?

Comment: so this is not a hard work dude, you just need to change the `fillRect()` values, I just gave you an example, now if the text is started from `x=100`, so just change the first value to 100. the just thing you need to know is the possible/exact place which every time you draw the text.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use the getGraphics() method to do painting. For future reference read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do something like this.

However, you should not even be using custom painting for this requirement. Instead you should just be using a `JLabel`. Then when you want to change the string you just invoke the `setText()` method of the label.